# Css анимация. Изображение сначала появилось, потом на него подействовала анимация

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть такой вопрос: Шапка сайта реализована так, что логотип и навигация красиво выезжают сверху и справа соответственно. Но есть проблема, а именно: сначала эти элементы появились на нужном месте, через долю секунды исчезли и выехали как нужно, согласно прописанной анимации..
Что нужно сделать, чтобы при загрузке страницы эти элементы не появлялись на экране до начала анимации?

Если нужно показать код чего-либо - предоставлю, просто его очень много, а что нужно именно я не знаю..

Comment: прозрачность добавь им, а в анимации допиши чтоб прозрачность убралась. но тогда на браузерах некоторых лого может вообще не появиться

Comment: сработало) спасибо)